# Files app not showing PDF thumbnails

Tags: pantheon-files, files

Files stopped showing PDF thumbnails. If I remove apparmor profile or adding new, it works as expected.

```
# bash -c "owner /tmp/tumbler-* w, >> /etc/apparmor.d/local/usr.bin.evince"
# apparmor_parser -r /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.evince
```

OR

```
# apparmor_parser -R /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.evince
```

Details of the packages:

```
apparmor    2.12-4ubuntu5.1
evince  3.28.4-0ubuntu1.2+elementary2~ubuntu5.0.1
pantheon-files  4.1.9+r3433+pkg82~ubuntu5.0.1
```

Comment: If you believe this to be a bug of Files, please report it @ https://github.com/elementary/files/issues

Comment: I am not sure if it's a bug of files app or evince app.

Comment: I added new rule to fix that issue.

Comment: Submitted issue: https://github.com/elementary/files/issues/1034